# How do I effectively switch functions in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python code that looks like

```
def bigFunction(x, function = 'smallFunctionA'):
  if function == 'smallFunctionA':
    return a(x)
  elif function == 'smallFunctionB':
    return b(x)
  ...
```

this works fine, but the code gets very redundant as it gets longer either I use if statements whenever I have to use a smallFunction, or I copy the whole body of the bigFunction for each smallFunctions.
Is there a way to make this more short and less redundant? I'm lost what keyword to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose is, but you can use a dictionary that maps function names with function objects:

```
def bigFunction(x, function = 'smallFunctionA'):
    map = {'smallFunctionA': a,
           'smallFunctionB': b}
    return map[function](x)
```

Comment: Thx helped a lot

Comment: It’s unclear whether a map from name to function is really needed or not. If you need that map, there’s no way for it not to grow...

Comment: @deceze Yes. From the example in the question I assumed that the OP has no control of the arguments and the function names, but apparently they do. In that case goodvibrations's answer is a better solution.

Comment: I don't understand the comments here,, doesn't this allow me to write like ```func = map[function]``` and then just use func for everything else?

Comment: @Rick1101 This method is useful if your function name (e.g. `a`) and the argument value you pass (e.g. `smallFunctionA`) **have to be** different. If you can rename your functions to `smallFunctionA` etc, then the other answer is better.

Comment: @goodvibration The time complexity of a dictionary lookup is `O(1)`.

Comment: @Selcuk I'm not sure yet, but I think what you said goes for me. Thx a lot

Comment: @Selcuk: That's not entirely true. First of all, the initializationtime is still `O(n)`, most particularly when you do it inside the function (just as you did). Second, even if you put it in global scope, the space complexity is still `O(n)`. In addition to all of that, like I said, the argument in the question remains - the code gets longer and longer.

Comment: @goodvibration So what is your suggestion, assuming that the OP is unable to rename their functions?

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
def bigFunction(x, function):
    return function(x)
```

And pass the actual function (not the function name as string).

Comment: Thx didn't knew that works

Comment: @Rick1101: You're welcome :)